# Rails callbacks triggering despite conditionals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a lot of trouble with this model, if someone could help. Currently, my code seems to be causing an infinite loop whenever it start update_attributes. I have tried a lot of different combinations to get this to stop, but nothing seems to work (except for very inefficient methods :( )

According to ActiveModel::Dirty, the link_url_changed method should only return true when the user has edited the link, but for some reason its returning true all the time and allows an infinite loop. How do get this to work?

I'd really like to 1. in a new record, the user submits a link, it is validated 2. if valid, a callback calls embedly to get more info on the link. 3. The new info is validated, then stored into the db 4. embedly is not called again! not until a user edits the link_url

Here's my code:

```
class ListLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::Dirty

    belongs_to :list
    default_scope -> {order('created_at DESC')}

    VALID_URL_REGEX = /\A(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www|)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?\z/i
    validates :link_url, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_URL_REGEX} 
    validates :list_id, presence: true

    before_save :embedly, if: "link_url_changed?"
    #need to trigger embedly only when link_url changes

    validates :title, presence: true#, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}
    validates :image_url, presence: true


  private
    def embedly
        logger.debug "embedly entered link changed!"
        #if self.errors.empty?
            embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
            #duplicate the url for use in the embedly API
            url = link_url.dup
            obj = embedly_api.extract :url => url

            update_attributes(:title => obj[0].title, :image_url => obj[0]["images"][0]["url"])
    end
end
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `update_attributes` in the callback method, it will trigger a new save. Just update the model like this:

```
self.title = obj[0].title
self.image_url = obj[0]["images"][0]["url"]
```

Comment: Ah yeah I was doing that before, but doesn't this skip validations? Do you have any recommendations on how to validate the data with this method?

Comment: @PaygeVii You could use `before_validation` instead of `before_save`, so the new title and image_url will be validated.

Comment: yes I tried before_validation before as well but then I couldn't get asynchornization to work. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaygeVii If `before_save` is better for you, you could use `self.valid?` at the end of the callback. Il the validation fails, the callback returns `false`, and the save is canceled.